# Can the subsidiary be a party to the contract signed by its parent here?

Tags: contract-law, india, corporate-law, shell-companies

A contract is worded to state that it has been executed between Customer A and my Client B. The expression Customer A is further clarified: "which expression shall unless repugnant to the context or meaning thereof, include its successors, administrators, executors, and assigns Does this mean a subsidiary of Customer A could also be construed as a party to the contract?

Answer (score 3):

### If they were a successor, administrator, executor, or assignee

A subsidiary company would not normally be one of those but there’s noting preventing them from becoming one - most likely an assignee.